# Creating a react App starts aborting installation

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

While creating a new react app, getting this error.

`Aborting installation.   yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd C:\Users\.... \my-app has failed.`

I know @5328 gave solution by removing . npmrc file here - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5328#issuecomment-429148117

I am new to react .. so can some one please let me know how do I find .npmrc file and how do i remove it? Or how do I create a new react app without having this error? 
I know we can create a react app with the following command: 
npx create-react-app my-app
or
yarn create react-app my-app
or
npm init react-app my-app

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look in your ```Users/YourName``` folder?

Answer (score 6):

Okay,

I solved this problem by following the below steps:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install node
npm install -g yarn
yarn cache clean
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while creating a new app with CRA.

I tried all the below-mentioned solution:
1) Uninstall Yarn and install again.
2) yarn cache clean
3) npm uninstall -g create-react-app and install again.

Here's main issue:
error @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.13.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "10.11.0"
error Found incompatible module.

You may have got something similar. Look a couple of lines above "Aborting installation"

In my case, I was using Node version "10.11.0". I install a stable version of Node and it worked absolutely fine.

To double-check I tried to simulate the issue by changing the version with the help of NVM, and got the same issue.

Please refer to the error message and you'll figure out the culprit.

Note: I would still suggest keeping the updated and stable version of Yarn and CRA.