# Create-next-app fails nvm node 16 doesn't work

Tags: node.js, next.js, nvm

Trying to create a new next app with `yarn create next-app`.
It fails with this error:

```
error @eslint/eslintrc@1.0.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0". Got "14.15.3"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact --cwd /Users/helenkent/Documents/Code/projects/lick-city-vote --dev eslint eslint-config-next has failed.
```

I upgraded my node version to 16, so when i check with `node --version` I get `v16.13.1`

When I tried to make the next app again I got the same error message as before, so its not seeing that I've upgraded node.

Don't really know what I'm doing when upgrading node so first I downloaded and clicked install on 16.13.1 from here https://nodejs.org/en/ but that didnt work when i checked the node version on the cmd line. Next I tried `nvm install 16` and `nvm use 16`. That then showed node version 16.13.1 but like I said above, it still didn't help with the error as its somehow still picking up v14.15.3

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: did you try downgrading node 14.17.0?

Comment: I just tried nvm install 14.17.0 and nvm use 14.17.0, tried again and got the same error - still thinks I have node 14.15.3

Answer (score 4):

1. npm install -g npm@latest
2. npm install node
3. npm install -g yarn
4. yarn cache clean
5. npx create-next-app@latest

Try these steps, I was facing the same error and after searching for 1 hour I found this solution. Although it was for react app, it work for me.
Here is the original solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252362/11674006